# java - How does BigInteger convert Strings to its internal representation?

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger

I am doing a little side project where I am delving into the implementation of some popular classes that we use in the Java Libraries.

The first on my list is [BigInteger](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java). I am interested in understanding basically the algorithm via which is converts a String into a number for internal representation.

This is the [piece of code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/6d511f1376e3a0183a484443d05142678bdaa1c2/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#LL527C9-L559C10) I am interested in:

```
// Pre-allocate array of expected size. May be too large but can
        // never be too small. Typically exact.
        long numBits = ((numDigits * bitsPerDigit[radix]) >>> 10) + 1;
        if (numBits + 31 >= (1L << 32)) {
            reportOverflow();
        }
        int numWords = (int) (numBits + 31) >>> 5;
        int[] magnitude = new int[numWords];

        // Process first (potentially short) digit group
        int firstGroupLen = numDigits % digitsPerInt[radix];
        if (firstGroupLen == 0)
            firstGroupLen = digitsPerInt[radix];
        String group = val.substring(cursor, cursor += firstGroupLen);
        magnitude[numWords - 1] = Integer.parseInt(group, radix);
        if (magnitude[numWords - 1] < 0)
            throw new NumberFormatException("Illegal digit");

        // Process remaining digit groups
        int superRadix = intRadix[radix];
        int groupVal = 0;
        while (cursor < len) {
            group = val.substring(cursor, cursor += digitsPerInt[radix]);
            groupVal = Integer.parseInt(group, radix);
            if (groupVal < 0)
                throw new NumberFormatException("Illegal digit");
            destructiveMulAdd(magnitude, superRadix, groupVal);
        }
        // Required for cases where the array was overallocated.
        mag = trustedStripLeadingZeroInts(magnitude);
        if (mag.length >= MAX_MAG_LENGTH) {
            checkRange();
        }
```

I kind of understand the previous lines. But here is when it does not make sense as the math used is not familiar.

My questions are as follows:

- What does `bitsPerDigit` signify ? If you run a debugger then it comes to `3402`. Is that the number of bits used in a digit in `int` in Java ?
- Why divide the result of `(numDigits * bitsPerDigit[radix])` by `2^10` and add `1` ? (Right logical shift is dividing a power by `2`).
- Why add `31` to the `numBits` before dividing by `2^5 = 32`? (I kind of understand 32 bits as that is the size of an `int` in Java).
- What is `destructiveMulAdd`? How does it work?

Are these algorithms documented somewhere?

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: The comment says `// bitsPerDigit in the given radix times 1024`

Comment: Because it's not a whole number of bits. It's approximately 3.32 bits per digit.

Comment: @harold Could you please add what `destructiveMulAdd` is ? Or at least please point me to where I can find more info about it.

Comment: @ng.newbie `destructiveMulAdd(x, y, z)` implements `x = (x * y) + z`, where `x` is a large number held in an array and `y` and `z` are normal-size integers. `x` is updated in-place, hence "destructive". The algorithm is just .. multiplication, and addition. Nothing fancy.

Comment: @harold Yes but why do this ? It is done during initialization. What possible use can it have during initialization ?

Comment: @ng.newbie normally when parsing a number represented in base 10 you might multiply by 10 and then add the next digit, right? `destructiveMulAdd` is used for both of those steps, but (assuming we still have `radix = 10`) 9 digits are parsed at the time so the multiplication is by a billion and then a number up to a billion is added.

Answer (score 2):

`bitsPerDigit[x]` is a [fixed-point approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) of log2(x), with a scale of 1024, and rounded up. Given that x = 10, we get an estimate of approximately `3402 / 1024 = 3.32226562` bits per digit (the actual log2(10) is closer to 3.3219). To be clear, 3402 represents 3.32226562, but we never actually calculate the latter, it is worked with implicitly.

The right-shift by 10 accounts for the scale of 1024, converting the result of the multiplication from a fixed-point format with 10 bits after the radix point to just a plain old integer. The right-shift rounds down, adding 1 compensates for that in a way that ensures the result is never too low, and never zero.

The conversion from the number of bits to the number of words, `(numBits + 31) >>> 5`, is just a division by 32 rounded up.

At every step we must round up to avoid allocating a too small array, but the size estimate does not need to be extremely accurate: estimating it a little too high only results in a little bit of wasted space in the internal array.

Comment: This is very detailed answer. However, I still need more clarification from you. Does `bitsPerDigit` mean the max amount bits needed for a digit with a radix of 10 ? So the max digit is `9` which is represented by `101` 3 binary bits. - Am I correct ?

Comment: What does `digitsPerInt` mean ? I am confused by how they are able to generalize this calculation for most radixes. Is this a standard algorithm ?

Comment: @ng.newbie `bitsPerDigit` is not the max amount of bits for a digit, that would always be an integer and using it would overestimate the size. 9 takes 4 bits by itself, but 999 does not take 12 bits (only 10) and in general the ratio of decimal digits to bits is not 4 but rather log2(10). So that is what `bitsPerDigit[10]` is (approximated in fixed-point).

Comment: yes 9 does not take 12 bits, it needs only 10. But 4*3 = 12 bits is exactly what the implementation uses. You can see that it multiplies the number of bits with the number of digits. https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/74dc50b7f0b0b9440746ff329fc3324c477ae421/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#L529

Comment: Also why is it scaled to 1024 ? That just feels so random, I know its 2^10 but why scale it ?

Comment: @ng.newbie for a decimal number of 3 digits it's using `(3402 * 3 >> 10) + 1 = 10` bits, not 12. Some scale (greater than 1) is used to increase accuracy, rounding log2(10) up to 4 would work but overestimates the size by a lot for large numbers. It didn't have to be 2^10, it could have been 2^8 or 2^12 or something similar.

Comment: Is the reason we are using `bitsPerDigit[10] = 3402` and not 3000 is because we want to allocate a little extra space but not as much space as it would be if we used  `bitsPerDigit[10] = 4000` ?

Comment: 3000 is too little, representing less than 3 (with a scale of 1024). 4000 is unnecessarily large, representing 3.90625 while log2(10) is only around 3.32226562. BTW to represent 4, the value in `bitsPerDigit` would need to be 4096 - so `bitsPerDigit[16] = 4096` because for base 16 you really do need 4 bits per hex-digit.

Comment: The goal is to multiply by 3.32226562.

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience. Do you think it would be easier for you to explain if I made a separate question ? Then I will do that.

Comment: I couldn't understand the `destructiveMulAdd(x, y, z)` so I made a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76476586/7134737