# java BigInteger - How does destructiveMulAdd convert a number to big endian magnitude?

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, biginteger

I am doing this side project where I try to understand the internal implementation of some of the widely used utility classes in Java.

I want to know how BigInteger store's the number internally.

What I found was that it is [using an int[]](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/57b8251241e2044d5039ce162bf4637a9b2e5466/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#L155) for storing the magnitude of a number in "big-endian" format.

It does this via the [destructiveMulAdd](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/57b8251241e2044d5039ce162bf4637a9b2e5466/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#L640) add function:

```
private static void destructiveMulAdd(int[] x, int y, int z) {
        // Perform the multiplication word by word
        long ylong = y & LONG_MASK;
        long zlong = z & LONG_MASK;
        int len = x.length;

        long product = 0;
        long carry = 0;
        for (int i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            product = ylong * (x[i] & LONG_MASK) + carry;
            x[i] = (int)product;
            carry = product >>> 32;
        }

        // Perform the addition
        long sum = (x[len-1] & LONG_MASK) + zlong;
        x[len-1] = (int)sum;
        carry = sum >>> 32;
        for (int i = len-2; i >= 0; i--) {
            sum = (x[i] & LONG_MASK) + carry;
            x[i] = (int)sum;
            carry = sum >>> 32;
        }
    }
```

What is really going on here ?

Using a debugger I was able to find out the following things:

1. Given a large number: segments of the number are broken down and [converted to integers](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/57b8251241e2044d5039ce162bf4637a9b2e5466/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#L550) and sent to this function along with something called a "superRadix" which for base 10 = 10^9
2. Once in the function both are converted to long [with some masking](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/57b8251241e2044d5039ce162bf4637a9b2e5466/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#L642) to preserve the sign bit.
3. `product` is calculated from the last index of the magnitude array by [multiplying with "superRadix" and adding the carry](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/57b8251241e2044d5039ce162bf4637a9b2e5466/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#L649).
4. The `product` is truncated to an int, ie. only least significant 32-bits from the 64-bit long are stored in `x[i]`.
5. The most significant bits of the product are shifted 32 places to occupy the place where the product was truncated. That becomes the `carry`.
6. The operation repeats till the last index of the magnitude array.

Next the summation phase begins:

1. The original segment `zlong` is added with the last content of the magnitude array to form the new `sum`.
2. The last index is set to the "int truncated" value of the `long sum` ie. only the least significant 32 bits are taken of the 64-bit `sum`.
3. `carry` is equal to setting `sum` shifted by 32 bits ie. taking the remaining non-truncated 32 bits of the 64 bit `sum`.
4. For some reason we start from `len-2` of the magnitude array and work backwards. Doing the same truncate and shift for `sum` and `carry`.

**My questions are as follows:**

1. In what way is the array storing the magnitude ? It seems like madness, it is taking the previously calculated value and then multiplying with new segment... ugghh
2. Shouldn't this be **little endian** ? For example given `12345678890123`, it will take the **leftmost** digits and put it `len-1`(last) index of the array. **So isn't it placing the most significant bits in the least significant array indexes ?**
3. What is going on with `superRadix` being 10^9 for base10 ?
4. What is the truncate and shift actually doing ? **Is it doing a mod then divide?**
5. Just basically how this entire thing is actually working ?

I wish there were better documentation of the algorithms used, however there is none I could find hence here I am.

Comment: This is an algorithm that you learned in elementary school, maybe you are confusing yourself with the implementation details but the algorithm itself is trivial. How do you multiply 123456 by 8? With this algorithm, probably. Multiply 6 by 8, write down an 8, carry the 4.. that's what's happening here but with a higher base.

Comment: Could you please go into more detail ? The internal representation of `12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890` looks like `[8, 1920951145, -1426572127, 1344697466, -121114218, -834729262]`. Could you please show an example with a higher base ? **How does the internal representation correlate to the actual number ?**

Comment: @harold I am unable to ascertain how this is just a simple multiplication.

Comment: Just as 123 means 3 * 10^0 + 2 * 10^1 + 1 * 10^2, here `int[] { 1, 2, 3 }` would mean 3 * (2^32)^0 + 2 * (2^32)^1 + 1 * (2^32)^2. Limbs with their highest bit set will be presented as being negative, but you're supposed to interpret them as unsigned values, which the code does by bitwise-ANDing them with `LONG_MASK`

Comment: @harold Ok maybe I am beginning to understand a bit. The base of the number is `10^9`, right? Each digit can have `0 - 10^9-1` symbols, right? Each digit is an element in the `int[]` array, right? So just like in decimal to add a digit to its correct position I multiply the partial number I have then add the digit to that, I am multiplying by `10^9` as that is the base we are using. So its `y*10^9 + z`, correct ?

Comment: @harold But then I have a confusion about the way the multiplication is being done. **Why is it multiplying each digit with the `radix` ?** That's not how the algorithm works right ? You are supposed to take the entire number as it is now right ?

Comment: The base of the number in the `int[]` is `2^32`, the base of the number being parsed is effectively `10^9` (by pulling out 9 digits and parsing them to an `int` first). We multiply the number in the `int[]` by `10^9`, because that's the base of the number being parsed (effectively), but that multiplication happens in a representation that is base `2^32`.

Comment: @harold Why not just convert base `10` to base `10^9` ? Why convert to base `2^32` ? Keeping it as `10^9` wont even have to change the representation. Each base `10^9` block can be one element in the `mag[]` array. **It seems so much easier. Where am I going wrong ?**

Comment: Absolutely, that would be much easier - for conversion to and from a (decimal) string. It would be less efficient to implement arithmetic on that representation, but it's possible and sometimes done that way. Java's `BigInteger` doesn't do it that way.

Comment: @harold Why do the comments in the code say that the magnitude is stored in `big-endian` format ? Shouldn't it be `little endian` as it parses the number from `left to right` but stores in the array from `right to left` ?

Comment: The most significant part of the number is stored at the lowest index, which is similar to big-endian although I normally only use that terminology for a byte order. That's why the loops for multiplication and addition are "backwards".

Comment: @harold How is implementing arithmetic on `2^32` easier than `10^9` ?

Comment: @harold When you say "lowest index" do you mean `len -1` index or `0` index ?

Comment: For the purposes of eg addition and multiplication: if you use base 2^32 you never have to use annoying operations such as modulo by 10^9 or divide by 10^9, just truncation and shift. Even worse, for the purposes of eg `bitCount`, `shiftRight`, `xor`, having a non-power-of-two base would be very annoying. By "lowest index" I just mean zero.

Comment: @harold Ok, I am unable to understand how the most significant part of the number is in `0` index. For example, take the number `1234567890123456789`, the implementation (verified via debugger) will take `12345` from the left and then put it in the `len - 1` index of the `mag` array. **So it is taking the most significant part of the number and placing it in highest index ie. `len - 1`**. **And isn't that little endian ?** Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: It just looks that way. If you look at the final result, or at how the arithmetic works, you will see that it's not so. The number in the `int[]` is iteratively changed by multiplying it by 10^9 and adding a chunk from the string. The *first* part of the string that gets added to it, starts at the least significant end of the `int[]` indeed, but then it gets multiplied by 10^9 the most times so it ends up in the most significant part eventually. Try parsing "340282367079394788547243514857164636165"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254109/discussion-between-harold-and-ng-newbie).

Comment: @harold Hey I now fully understand the `destructivemuladd` thanks to you. But I still am not entirely sure about why use `10^9` as the radix and not `10^10`. A 32-bit integer in Java can have 10 digits, so why restrict yourself to 9 digits on each iteration ?

Comment: There are some ints that have 10 digits in decimal, but not all numbers that have 10 digits in decimal fit in an int.

Comment: @harold I don't understand, can you please elaborate? The 32-bit int can store 10 digits, right? so why place only 9 digits in it? is it to protect against overflows? it slices it up into 9 digits on each iteration, I just feel 10 digits would be a more efficient utilization of space.

Comment: Even when using int in an unsigned way (`parseUnsignedInt` etc), it can still only go up to 4,294,967,295, but 10 digit numbers go up to 9,999,999,999 so over half of them don't fit

Comment: @harold I can't thank you enough. I wish you would just compile these points and add it into an answer.